# VBA ACCESS FORM EDITING ISSUE AFTER Do.CMD.FindRecord

Tags: vba, ms-access

```
strSQL = " select top 1 id from employees "
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
If Not rs.EOF Then 
DoCmd.FindRecord rs(0), , True, , True 
rs.Close
End If
```

the Error is a Write Conflict with the Save Record grayed out.
The DoCMD line is whats causing the error.
I am trying to automate when someone enters an ID and its already there to go to that record.
I have this working but when I try to edit the form I get an error stating that someone else
is trying to use the same form. I have isolated the code that is causing it but can't figure
out how to fix it.

Comment: Could probably use DMax() instead of opening a recordset object. However, that probably will not resolve the issue. Nothing in that code is editing data. I tested code and have no problem editing record that is found.

Comment: What event is code in?

Answer (score 0):

Rebooted that didn't help so I moved the table from sql to Access and that sovled it.

Comment: Did you mean SQLServer? Works with my SQLServer table. Had to use `dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges` because of IDENTITY field for the recordset. DMax() was simpler.